# How to get list of all databases using MongodbClient class. (C# application)

Tags: c#, wpf, mongodb

I am using MongoDB driver, to communicate with Mongo database. I have a need where I need display all available databases. The library has only on method that says 'GetDatabase("dbname"). What is the way to get all dbs available in ny code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how you can get the list of dbs

```
MongoClient client = new MongoClient("mongodb://localhost:27017");
List<string> dbs = new List<string>();
using (IAsyncCursor<BsonDocument> cursor = client.ListDatabases())
{
    while (cursor.MoveNext())
    {
        foreach (var doc in cursor.Current)
            dbs.Add((string)doc["name"]); // database name
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answers , but if do ' show dbs' on mongo server it is responding with the names admin, config, local, test. I want to access them in my C# code.  From the above code I am getting an error ''Argument1 : Cannot convert MongoDB.Bson.BsonValve to String" at  code 'dbs.Add(doc["name"]); // database name' from the above given answer

Comment: "dbs.Add(doc["name"]);" , This where it is giving me problem.

Comment: Finally it worked , with correction of   "dbs.Add(doc["name"]);"  to                                              "dbs.Add(doc["name"].ToString()"

Comment: Do cast it to string. `(string)doc["name"]`